# Postgresql archive_command suddenly stopped to work

Tags: postgresql, windows, rsync, archive

Yesterday it just stopped to send WALs to remote destination, I was using rsync on Windows.
There are no error in logs.

`archive_mode` is of course **on**

What is really strange that Postgres seems to stop executing archive_command at all, because there are no errors even if I change archive_command setting to something like this:

```
2023-08-16 21:58:28.554 +04,,,4540,,649a4a65.11bc,473,,2023-06-27 06:33:09 +04,,0,LOG,00000,
"parameter ""archive_command"" changed to ""test""",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
```

Usually it should throw an error that archive_command is invalid os something similar as I remember.